# Fast Named Entity Removal with NLTK

Tags: python, optimization, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I wrote a couple of user defined functions to remove named entities (using NLTK) in Python from a list of text sentences/paragraphs. The problem I'm having is that my method is very slow, especially for large amounts of data. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to optimize this to make it run faster?

```
import nltk
import string

# Function to reverse tokenization
def untokenize(tokens):
    return("".join([" "+i if not i.startswith("'") and i not in string.punctuation else i for i in tokens]).strip())

# Remove named entities
def ne_removal(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    chunked = nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(tokens))
    tokens = [leaf[0] for leaf in chunked if type(leaf) != nltk.Tree]
    return(untokenize(tokens))
```

To use the code I typically have a text list and call the `ne_removal` function through a list comprehension. Example below:

```
text_list = ["Bob Smith went to the store.", "Jane Doe is my friend."]
named_entities_removed = [ne_removal(text) for text in text_list]
print(named_entities_removed)
## OUT: ['went to the store.', 'is my friend.']
```

UPDATE: I tried switching to batch version with this code, but it's only slightly faster. Will keep exploring. Thanks for the input so far.

```
def extract_nonentities(tree):
    tokens = [leaf[0] for leaf in tree if type(leaf) != nltk.Tree]
    return(untokenize(tokens))

def fast_ne_removal(text_list):
    token_list = [nltk.word_tokenize(text) for text in text_list]
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag_sents(token_list)
    chunked = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged)
    non_entities = []
    for tree in chunked:
        non_entities.append(extract_nonentities(tree))
    return(non_entities)
```

Comment: I'm not sure migration to codereview is appropriate. Excessively slow code _is_ a problem, this is not about "can I structure my code better".

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `ne_chunk()`, it needs to initialize a chunker object and load the statistical model for chunking from disk. Ditto for `pos_tag()`. So instead of calling them on one sentence at a time, call their batch versions on the complete list of texts:

```
all_data = [ nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in list_of_all_sents ]
tagged = nltk.pos_tag_sents(all_data)
chunked = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged)
```

This should give you a considerable speed-up. If that's still too slow for your needs, try profiling your code and consider whether you need to switch to more high-powered tools, like @Lenz suggested.

Comment: Also, the test `i not in string.punctuation` looks up `i` by searching in a string. Replacing `string.punctuation` with a set (defined globally) will dramatically speed up this line-- I couldn't predict whether this is a significant part of the total runtime, though, since tagging and chunking are much more time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks! I am playing around with the batch version (code added to original post). I timed it on 1,000 sentences and it's slightly faster (78.9 seconds vs. 82.5 the old way), but not significantly. I might explore using spaCy's named entity tagger as an easier way of speeding things up. I'll try the `string.punctuation` change too though first.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to hear that; it should have made a big difference, unless there's something wrong with your code. But don't waste your time installing other taggers until you've thoroughly profiled your current code and understand where the time is going. Make sure it's not something stupid like inefficient management of your primary data, for example.